# How can I get magento order array in cart.html

Tags: magento

How can I get magento order array in cart.phtml??

I need to know how many products is setting in an order and its respectives categories. I did try many codes but without success.

```
$session= Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
$items = $session->getQuote()->getAllItems();

print_r($items);
```

its result :  Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 247201792 bytes)

Comment: Show your code - even if it did not work. Well, actually, **especially** if it did not work.

Comment: I just added a code try